# shadow not working on png files

Tags: android, wear-os

I have made an watch face with custom PNG for hour, minute and second hands, used the android studio script to make the watch face and all is well when i use it on my huawei w1 watch but the 
    SHADOW_RADIUS 
is not showing the shadow on the watch hands...
Pieces of code...

```
private static final int SHADOW_RADIUS = 6;
```

on the onCreate

```
mWatchHandShadowColor = Color.BLACK;
mHourPaint = new Paint();
mHourPaint.setColor(mWatchHandColor);
mHourPaint.setStrokeWidth(HOUR_STROKE_WIDTH);
mHourPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
mHourPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
mHourPaint.setShadowLayer(SHADOW_RADIUS, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
```

On the updateWatchHandStyle

```
mHourPaint.setShadowLayer(SHADOW_RADIUS, 0, 0, mWatchHandShadowColor);
```

Any tips on how to get it working?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the format in this [sample code](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/complications/blob/master/1-base/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/complications/ComplicationWatchFaceService.java). `mHourPaint.setShadowLayer(SHADOW_RADIUS, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);` Maybe the `mWatchHandShadowColor` method is not called in your `updateWatchHandStyle`.

Comment: Thank you for the sample code but already tried that. Still... no results on PNG customized hour, minute and second hands.